# How can I merge two rows to one row?

Tags: list-manipulation

I know it may sounds idiot, but I couldn't find a way to combine two rows say {a, b} and {c, d} into {a, c, b, d}.

Comment: `Flatten[Transpose[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]]`?

Comment: `Flatten@Thread[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]`

Comment: Flatten@{{a, b}, {c, d}} + {0, -b + c, b - c, 0}

Comment: `Riffle @@ {{a, b}, {c, d}}`

Comment: I wonder if this was a typo, and the OP  needed just `Join[{a,b},{c,d}]`. Is that a common way to *merge* lists?

Comment: What I need is to write a code that merge any number of rows to only and only one row. Thanks for your comments though!

Comment: @Mutaz what is the input, `{{a, b}, {c, d}}` or just a sequence of arguments: `{a, b}, {c, d}`? What is the expected output for three rows e.g. `{a,b}, {c,d}, {e,f}`?

Comment: `Inner[List, {a, b}, {c, d}, Join]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Flatten[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {2, 1}]
```

> {a, c, b, d}